# Python , nested list row and column

Tags: python, pygame, nested-lists

My first time here.
I permit to ask some advice on python nested list.
I actually try to use python and pygame to make a simple grid based game.
I want to use a list of list to hold the map where my char is moving.
so here is my map:

```
basic_map=[['NW',1,1,1,'NE'],
           [1,0,0,0,1],
           [1,0,0,0,1],
           [1,0,0,0,1],
           ['SW',1,1,1,'SE']]
```

a square, four corner with direction in each.
then i use a nested for to draw the map:

```
for x in range (5):
        for y in range (5):
            str3=str(basic_map[x][y])  
            text3=font.render(str3,True,white)
            screen.blit(text3,(100+40*x,100+40*y))
```

here start my problem, i don't understand why my map is displayed with inverted row and column.
i have a solution, invert x and y when displaying, but then the movement will not be ok, since north is (x=0,y=-1) will behave as east and so on.

i don't understand why i am stuck since one week on this basic thing.
i have searched a lot throught internet and also asked throught IRC but have not been lucky.

i don't ask a ready to use code but a simple explanation to understand my fault.hope you will understand what i am saying since i am not an english native.

Thanks by advance

Comment: What is wrong? Please show us expected output and actual output

Comment: M Careaga show exctalty the output in different way.I should have posted them sorry for that since i am not used to this board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i run this i get this output

[image]

so what you could do is just switch the `NE` and the `SW` so that it works

it will look like this:

[image]

to see why this works add a `0` in to youre map lists so it looks like this:

```
self.basic_map=[['NW',1,0,1,'SW'],
           [1,0,0,0,1],
           [1,0,0,0,1],
           [1,0,0,0,1],
           ['NE',1,0,1,'SE']]
```

when you run that it outputs this:

[image]

even though you put the `0`s in on the top and bottom row the program put the `0`s in on the sides so it basically takeing youre map and turning it so that the horizontal rows become vertical colums

hope this help :)

Comment: sorry to not have posted shots, since you do it, it exactly define the way things are.

Comment: finally a friend of mine that is pretty good to java programming give me a function to have the map displayed correctly 'code' def adjustMap (some_map):
    y = 0
    while y < len(some_map):
        x = 0
        while x < y:
            a = some_map[y][x]
            some_map[y][x] = some_map[x][y]
            some_map[x][y] = a
            x += 1
        y += 1

Comment: Oh nice! there you go!

Answer (score 0):

When accessing a multi-dimensional list, there are 2 integers to use for the indeces `[x][y]`, for example. In your case, you are putting x in the first brackets. This is the getter for the xth list INSIDE the outer list. This is because the map you have set up in basically a list where each item in the list is a row in the map and each row consists of elements of the overall columns. the x-dimension variable should be used to access items in the ROW lists. Try setting up the map like this:

```
basic_map = [['NW',1,1,1'SW'],
             [1,0,0,0,1],
             [1,0,0,0,1],
             [1,0,0,0,1],
             ['NE',1,1,1,'SE']]
```

It may seem counter-intuitive but it will let you access the grids on the map more intuitively like you want.

Comment: ok, i understand your explanation, and the solution, but i would really like to keep my map writen as i wrote it, because of readability and easyness of design. So i must find a good way to swap x,y to act as the map was designed...also i would be opened to another way but map must stay readable.I thank you alot for your time.